Github actions/AWS ECS/ECR: structuring a multi-environment deployment system
I want to set up our CI/CD with github actions roughly as follows:

When a new commit (or head of a branch) is pushed:

Run tests
Build docker image with a tag that matches the git sha
Push image to AWS


When a main branch is updated

Deploy the docker image with the git sha on the staging ECS cluster.


When a production branch is updated

Deploy the docker image with the git sha on the production ECS cluster.



The problem I'm facing is that every workflow starts with a set of trigger events, and for each of these 3 goals the trigger events are different.
If these were all part of the same workflow, I could use needs to make 2 and 3 wait for 1, but given that they have different triggers (on), I don't think this is possible.
My current solution is for both the staging and production workflows to do their own build, but this feels wasteful. Even though ECR recognizes existing layers when pushing, on the Github Actions side everything has to happen from scratch.

It'd be great to have a sample of your workflow file to be able to help you better. I guess the tests,  build, push and deploy belong each to different jobs right? Also given the different scenarios you have, have you tried using if and filtering using the git.ref_name?
